# Using delete on pointer to std::list?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdlist

In my program I have a pointer to a `std::list` object, it is allocated like so.

```
d_list_p = new std::list<some_type*>();
```

Then later in my program I delete it like so.

```
d_list_p->clear();
delete d_list_p;
```

For some reason I'm getting a Windows breakpoint triggered on the delete statement. If I break at the delete statement I see that the list exists and has a size of 0. Also, I never add an element to the list for the case that throws an error (I think).

The code is being compiled with the MS VC++ compiler for VS2005.

The error message says Windows triggered a breakpoint indicating memory corruption. The stack trace says the following.

```
ntdll.dll!DbgBreakPoint()   
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey()  + 0x6735 bytes  
ntdll.dll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey()  + 0x6b72 bytes  
ntdll.dll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey()  + 0x7d5a bytes  
ntdll.dll!LdrAlternateResourcesEnabled()  + 0x33bd bytes    
ntdll.dll!RtlpUnWaitCriticalSection()  + 0x65b bytes    
msvcr80.dll!free()  + 0xcd bytes    
FM_Access_Library_NET.dll!std::list<FM_Access_Library::Logger_Callbacks *,std::allocator<FM_Access_Library::Logger_Callbacks *> >::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x20 bytes C++
```

It is probably worth mentioning that this delete statement is in C++ code that is being built into a .NET DLL, so the program is running in mixed-mode.

Comment: You could be (and probably is) something else that is corrupting the memory.

Comment: Well, you have memory corruption somewhere. There's not enough here to know where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `d_list_p` a member of a class? And, does that class observe the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)?

If not, then (a copy of) `d_list_p` may have already been deleted.

Comment: `d_list_p->clear();` seems to have executed.  Most builds that would  brake on the delete, would also delete on the `clear()` line if it was already deleted.  (Although, not guaranteed.  You may still be right)

Comment: @Mooing, you may be right. I don't have Windows handy, but you'd certainly be right if they use a K&R-style malloc, where the free header encroaches on the free'd memory?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bebs9zyz(v=VS.71).aspx  debug builds replace free'd memory with 0xDD it looks like, and no-mans-land buffers on either side with 0xFD.

Comment: Yup, you called it. I was copying that list pointer in a copy constructor, so I had multiple deletes, because the delete was taking place in the destructor for the class that owned the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate your list and delete all individual pointers in it too, because you're leaking them if you don't.

And why are you creating a pointer to std::list? just use `std::list<mytype> mylist;`

Comment: Is there a missing "if" in the first sentence?

Comment: @Tomalak, there is no question. Re-read the OP, tell me if you can find a question in there.

Comment: +1 for "Why are you creating a pointer to `std::list`?"  There is almost never a reason to `new` an std container.

Comment: @Rob: There not being a question is not an excuse to write a not-answer as an answer. Write a comment, instead.

Comment: @Rob: That's silly. There are plenty of scenarios where you want a container to outlive the scope in which you create it.

Comment: It's also possible that the list does not "own" the pointers, and they should not be free'd when the list goes out of scope.  (Unlikely, but possible), and this is unrelated to the problem the OP "asked" about.

Comment: Yes, in my situation it is necessary to have a pointer to a list, because under certain circumstances I need to point to a different list and under some circumstances I need to delete the list. Apparently I'm deleting under the wrong circumstances though.

Comment: I also don't own the pointers in the list, so I don't delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doublechecks the heap when you call `delete`, and so the `delete` line is *finding* the error, not creating it.  The error is in the lines above.
Most heap corruption is caused by (A) calling delete too many times (B) calling the wrong form of delete, or (C) accessing a heap-allocated array out of bounds.  We can see that A and B aren't the issue, so It's probably C.  Find array accesses, and surround them asserts to validate the ranges.

Comment: -1, Heap? What is heap? There is no heap mentioned in the C++ Standard.

Comment: Does windows do a root check (or whatever the right term is) to see if you're deleting memory that is currently referenced elsewhere? At least while you're running the debugger. Because it looks like this is how it found the error.

Comment: @Als: It's fine that heap is not mentioned in the standard, since I never mentioned the standard, and the question is not a standards issue.  My answer is an explanation for the observed behavior, and a suggestion for how to address the problem.

Comment: @Mooing: How is it fine, if it is not correct(Why? My first comment addressed that already)?

Comment: @Ian: windows doesn't do a "root" check.  In debug builds, MSVC will put magic constants into out-of-bounds areas, and different magic constants into deleted memory.  You have accidentally changed those values, so Windows is telling you that you wrote past the end of an array.  In a release build, it may simply crash or do completely random things.

Comment: @Als: I agree that the heap is not mentioned in the standard.  Nevertheless, I believe heap corruption is the _direct_ cause of the observed behavior of the problem.  Just because it's not in the standard doesn't mean it doesn't exist in implementation.