# C++ Heap Corruption on Delete, Custom List

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm writing a basic List class. It's backed by an array, not a vector, because we aren't allowed to use vectors.

I seem to be running into heap corruption issues when I call `delete[]` on my internal backing array.

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::Remove( int elementIndex )
{
    // Here, I'm creating a new array of one less size to copy all elements over
    T* newArray = new T[Count - 1];
    bool skippedElement = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == elementIndex)
                skippedElement = true;

        newArray[i] = array[ skippedElement ? i + 1 : i ];
    }

    delete[] array; // Heap corruption!  See below for definition of array
    array = newArray;

    Count--;
    Capacity--;
}
```

**List.h**

```
class List
{
    ...
    private:
    T* array;
    ...

    template <typename T>
    List<T>::List( void )
    {
        array = new T[1];
    }

    template <typename T>
    List<T>::~List( void )
    {
        delete[] array;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why this is occuring?

According to [this useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7351858/555547), it says:

"*Most heap corruption is caused by (A) calling delete too many times (B) calling the wrong form of delete, or (C) accessing a heap-allocated array out of bounds.*"

I'm just not sure whether A, B, or/and C are true. Am I calling delete after it's already deleted? I don't think so. I also think I'm calling the right form of delete: delete with brackets. And I sure hope not C.

Comment: What is array? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, gonna be heavily editing for the next few minutes, just wanted the question up first.

Comment: Think about the index you're assigning to when `i == Count - 1` and you skipped something.

Comment: Is the given array an array of primitives or objects, or maybe even object pointers? If it's object pointers, such as List<MyObject*>, then you'll need to be calling delete on that object before skipping it out of the list. delete[] does not deal with this, it only deals with the space that you free'd up for the array (right?)

Comment: @MintAnt, this is an array of custom objects. List<Road>.

Comment: You don't show it, but I guess you initialize `Count`? Also, you have copy-constructor/copy-assignment operator? (e.g. [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29))

Comment: This is a very inefficient structure for a list. the copying time will kill any application that makes heavy use of this. Linked list is the way to go. Or you could allocate a larger-than-needed array and then pretend to add and remove items to it (and only expose items in the used part of the array to the user).

Comment: You're right. Maybe I can make a LinkedList in 20 minutes. Deadline at 11:59:59 P.M. The array is 220,000 items long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop you are iterating `Count` no of times. But your new array can hold only `Count - 1` number of elements. This leads to a heap corruption.

Comment: That seems to do it. Thank you.